# Joining on column with different prefix & name

Tags: sql, ssms

Relatively new to SQL querying. I'm trying to join two tables on an account number. However the account number appears in one table with a prefix of two extra digits.

For example, it appears in table A as 12345678 and in table B as 0012345678.

The name of the fields in each table is also different.

```
select a.AccountNumber, b.AccountNo
from dbo.TableA a
inner join dbo.TableB b
on a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNo
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Look into the CONCAT function. Something like: `ON CONCAT('00', a.AccountNumber) = b.AccountNo`

Comment: Thanks, CONCAT worked. I'm not sure why RIGHT didn't work but I was getting an error message saying conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the account number is 8 characters, please try:

```
select a.AccountNumber, b.AccountNo
from dbo.TableA a
inner join dbo.TableB b
on a.AccountNumber = RIGHT(b.AccountNo,8)
```

Comment: . . Your assumption is unnecessary.  The OP states that two digits are prepended on the account.